# Get the current transaction handle in interface method

Tags: kotlin, jdbi, jdbi3-core

I'm trying to gain access to the current JDBI transaction `handle` in my interface method, the purpose of this is to avoid passing the `handle` as an argument to the interface's methods, thus keeping the interface free of any implementation details. The following example demonstrates what the intended use case is.

I have a `UserApplicationService` managing the transaction being used

```
class UserApplicationService(val jdbi: Jdbi, val userRepository: UserRepository) {

    fun changeUserName() {
        jdbi.useTransaction<Exception> {
            userRepository.updateName("peter pan")
        }
    }
}
```

I have a `UserRepository` interface

```
interface UserRepository {
    fun updateName(name: String)
}
```

I have a `PostgresUserRepository` implementation of the interface

```
class PostgresUserRepository: UserRepository {
    override fun updateName(name: String) {
        val handle: Handle = getHandle() // some method to get the handle of the transaction, this is what I need help solving
        handle.execute("...") // set new name of user using the handle
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that you'd want to pass something to the constructor of `PostgresUserRepository` that would allow you to later get at the transaction handle.  Since that object is the implementation detail for the interface, it's fine for it to know about this specific thing.  This would likely be something you'd inject into the object at creation time.  Another option would be some sort of global variable, like a singleton object of a particular class that would be able to provide the handle.  Exactly what is best in your case will be a function of how the rest of your app is defined.

Comment: @Steve Not sure what I'd pass into the constructor of `PostgresUserRepository`, except for maybe the `Jdbi` object in case there is some method in it to get the current transaction. As for singletons; do you have an example of such an implementation?

Comment: Singleton pattern is a class with a static 'get()' method that returns an instance of the class.  The first time it is called, it allocates an instance of the object, saves a reference to that object away, and returns the reference.  on subsequent calls it returns the existing object via that reference.  Since you can call a static class method from anywhere in your code with no context, it's basically a global, ie: `MySingletonClass msc = MySingletonClass.get();`

Comment: Nailing down just what you want to access, and when and how it becomes available, seems to be the crux of your problem.  How to get that access seems secondary.  So I'd suggest that you try to answer that first question, and then present that here.  Or maybe someone will read this and can supply that answer.